# React application failing to run production while dev runs successfully - "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

I recently tried to push changes to a React application to Heroku. The application runs fine in dev, and the previous version runs fine on Heroku. However, after running *npm run build* in order to test the new version, it completely crashes.

Cloning the previous version from Heroku and running build, even without changes, causes the same issue. Console shows the following message:

[Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call') at f ((index):1:935)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mc4wR.png)

The screen itself is completely blank. Looking at index it seems to be in the following line:

```
return l[e].call(r.exports, r, r.exports, f),
```

I would include more, but it's non-human readable JS found in index.html produced in the build process.

There are references to lines of code, but upon removing these supposedly problematic lines a new line just ends up producing the same error. All errors, regardless of where they're found in the app, are located in main.xxxxxx.chunk.js in the build.

I've tried updating packages, starting a new create-react-app and copying over src and public, and deleting package-lock and node modules for a reinstall. Nothing has worked.

Terminal output is as follows:

```
 HTTP  16/06/2023 16:14:42 ::1 GET /
 HTTP  16/06/2023 16:14:42 ::1 Returned 200 in 15 ms
 HTTP  16/06/2023 16:14:42 ::1 GET /static/css/main.8ba163ce.chunk.css
 HTTP  16/06/2023 16:14:42 ::1 GET /static/js/2.2dec7b38.chunk.js
 HTTP  16/06/2023 16:14:42 ::1 GET /static/js/main.9df12165.chunk.js
 HTTP  16/06/2023 16:14:42 ::1 Returned 200 in 8 ms
 HTTP  16/06/2023 16:14:42 ::1 Returned 200 in 5 ms
 HTTP  16/06/2023 16:14:42 ::1 Returned 200 in 13 ms
 HTTP  16/06/2023 16:14:42 ::1 GET /favicon.ico
 HTTP  16/06/2023 16:14:42 ::1 Returned 200 in 2 ms
```

Relevant parts of package.json

```
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.18.3",
    "npm": "6.14.15"
  }
```

```
  "dependencies": {
      CONTAINS OTHERS BUT MOST LIKELY NOT RELEVANT

    "generate-webpack-config": "^2.0.3",
    "node-pre-gyp": "^0.17.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "serve": "^14.1.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "serve -s build",
    "dev": "react-scripts start --max_old_space_size=2560",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Webpack.config.js

```
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin').CleanWebpackPlugin;
const CommonConfigWebpackPlugin = require('common-config-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    // Cleans the dist folder before the build starts
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    // Multi threading babel loader configuration with caching for .js and .jsx files
    // Multi threading typescript loader configuration with caching for .ts and .tsx files
    // SCSS Configuration for .css .module.css and .scss .module.scss files
    // File loader configuration for .woff and .woff2 files
    // File loader configuration for .gif .jpg .jpeg .png and .svg files
    // https://github.com/merkle-open/webpack-config-plugins/
    new CommonConfigWebpackPlugin(),
    // Generate a base html file and injects all generated css and js files
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin(),
  ],
};
```

I have noticed that my node and npm values are higher on the system than specified in package.json, but changing the values in package.json makes no difference.

What's a good way of going about this? I'm completely stumped, as I haven't changed anything except component/page files using modules used throughout the application. I'm sure the issue is with webpack, but I'm unsure of what it could be.